# Beaker as session middleware

Tags: python, bottle, beaker

I'm writing an app using bottle.py and `beaker.middleware.SessionMiddleware`:

How can I modify the `session.timeout` and `session.cookie_expires` values so I can implement a login system that logs the user in for 30 days?

I already implemented the standard login system so everything works until the browser closes, but I'd like to modify those values if the user checks the *Remember me* checkbox.

I thought of two variants if the user checks the *Remember me* checkbox:

- Set `session.cookie_expires` and `session.timeout` to 30 days, but it seems that I can't modify these values at run-time because the cookie I recieve expires at the end of the browser session, ignoring my runtime modifications.
- Set `session.timeout` to 30 days and overwrite the cookie named `beaker.session.id` writing the same session id but different expiry date.
  But the run-time problem from point 1. remains and it seems that I can't access the session's id that I just created with beaker, so I don't know what to store in the cookie.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I come up with is to implement my own little backend and setting cookies myself, without beaker.

For posterity's sake, the code is here:
https://github.com/paulbarbu/bottle-upload/blob/master/index.py
Methods: `login_bl`, `upload_view(db)`, `is_logged_in`, and `logout()`.
Please note this is some VERY old code and NOT production ready, use at your own risk, some code snippets from the above link follow:

Login:

```
@post('/login')
def login_bl(db):
import hashlib

nick = request.forms.nick.lower()
password = hashlib.sha1(request.forms.password).hexdigest()

message = {}
error = None

uid  = get_user_id(db, nick, password)

if uid:
    sess = request.environ.get('beaker.session')
    sess['uid'] = uid
    # .... do other stuff for the logged in user
```

Logout:

```
@get('/logout')
def logout():
if not is_logged_in():
    redirect('/login')
else:
    sess = request.environ.get('beaker.session')
    sess.delete()

return template('logout.tpl')
```

Is the user logged in?

```
def is_logged_in():
'''Check whether the user sent a cookie that holds a Beaker created
session id
'''

sess_id = request.cookies.get('beaker.session.id', False)

if not sess_id:
    return False

sess = request.environ.get('beaker.session')

if 'uid' not in sess:
    return False

return True
```

Comment: yep.  we did the same thing: https://github.com/keredson/drsession  it's trivially easy.